# ios charts - Display labels on inside of axis

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

This is what my graph currently looks like.

[image: current graph]

[image: desired graph]

I am trying to put the axis labels on the right side of the left axis in ios charts by danielgindi as seen in the second picture above. Any suggestions, I have checked countless forums and posts send help.

Comment: Its already inside your graph what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @CodeChanger Sorry for being unclear, the above picture is taken from an already existing app. My graph currently looks like this https://ibb.co/kQVRTJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your requirement you can use below property to get your YAxis labels inside chart.

**Swift :**

```
lineChartView.leftAxis.labelPosition = .insideChart
lineChartView.rightAxis.labelPosition = .insideChart
```

**Objective-C:**

```
self.lineChart.leftAxis.labelPosition = YAxisLabelPositionInsideChart;
self.lineChart.rightAxis.labelPosition = YAxisLabelPositionInsideChart;
```

Hope this will helps!

Output :

[image]

Comment: thats exactly it, thank you